# What happens if you Teleport into a wall?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

A Wizard casts the Teleport spell, and the DM rolls "Off-Target" such that the destination moves to be in a wall, or other solid obstruction.

What happens? Is the Wizard

1. Instantly killed?
2. Shifted to the closest empty space?
3. Subject to taking an amount of damage?

Comment: I am somewhat surprised not to find a question on this already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You could use the existing "false destination" option

The [*Teleport*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport) spell describes probabilities of what happens based on your familiarity with the destination. One of the options is "false destination":

> "False destination" is a place that doesn't exist. Perhaps you tried to scry an enemy's sanctum but instead viewed an illusion, or you are attempting to teleport to a familiar location that no longer exists.

Attempting to teleport into a wall isn't precisely the same as attempting to teleport to a nonexistent location, but I believe the idea is similar enough. Certainly, if you intentionally tried to teleport to a room on the other side of a wall, but it turns out that behind the wall is just solid stone rather than a room, that would fall under "false destination". In this case, you're not intentionally teleporting into a wall, but rather being sent there due to an off-target teleport, but otherwise the situation is similar. So, in absence of any other rules about what happens in this situation, it's reasonable to decide by rolling on the "false destination" table. Essentially, I'm extending "False destination" to also encompass "Invalid destination". (Note that you could also extend this to other "invalid" destinations, such as a location that is warded against teleportation by a [*Forbiddance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance) spell.)

Note that when you roll a "similar area" result, you should probably choose an area similar to the *intended* destination, as opposed to just choosing another similar wall/rock to teleport them into. If you use this to resolve teleporting off-target into a wall, the end result will be that **the caster ends up maybe taking one or more rounds of "mishap" damage before being dropped in an area near the off-target location that is similar to the intended destination.** You can describe any resulting force damage from mishap rolls as damage that they take due to the spell trying and failing to teleport them into the wall before redirecting somewhere else.

Answer (score 15):

## It's up the DM

Essentially the DM picks the drop-off location. Unless you're teleporting only a few hundred feet tops (which seems unlikely with a spell like this) then the area you are teleporting to is likely not completely mapped out. Which means the DM will just make up a landing location. If they pick the inside of a wall, that mostly seems arbitrary. So at that point; saying the Wizard dies is an option, although not a very fun one.

More likely is the DM will pick some kind of nearby place that has enough room for the Wizard to arrive in.

Comment: heh, the *teleporting creature dies* happened in my first campaign (OD&D) and we mostly reacted by saying "arrgh, terrible die roll" and the player rolled up another character. Not sure if that was "unfun" but it was "the way the cookie crumbles"

Answer (score 6):

I would use the 3.5 edition Dimension Door spell as a guide.

It combines a shunt with damage thusly: Should the destination be occupied, the caster + creatures traveling with them takes 1d6 points of damage and is moved into a random unoccupied location no more than 100ft from the target destination. If there are no unoccupied spaces within range, the caster + creatures traveling with them take an additional 2d6 damage, and are moved to a random unoccupied location within 1000ft of the original target. If that is also impossible, the spell fails, and the caster + creatures traveling with them take an additional 4d6 damage (for a total of 7d6).

Source: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm

In 5th Edition, the Player's Handbook has similar rules for dimension door, but is simpler - if the space is occupied, caster + creatures travelling with them take 4d6 force damage and the spell fails (PHB pg.235).

As a DM, I say this is worse. While the maximum damage potential is less, it leaves out some of the finesse. If they are unlucky and end up in a castle wall, then it is a small amount of damage and they 'pop-out' at the destination. If they are very unlucky, and end up 200ft under ground, you give them more damage, and they appear any distance between 0 and 800 feet above ground. If this is not their day, and they would be in a mountain, well, they get a belting and stay where they are, a consolation for not being entombed.

5th edition would have all of those cases take a good deal of damage, and they stay in spot. Less interesting, and they lose the spell slot and materials without getting anything.

Comment: Nice job explaining why an adaptation of the other editions rules gives the DM a better dial to turn rather than an on/off choice.

Answer (score 4):

### Teleporting off-target isn't really to any degree of precision

If you look at the example for teleporting off-target, it's measuring in *miles*:

> For example, if you tried to travel 120 miles, landed off target, and rolled a 5 and 3 on the two d10s, then you would be off target by 15 percent, or 18 miles.

I don't think this is talking about a measurement of *exactly* 120.0000 miles between some centroid of 9 creatures within a 10-foot-radius sphere to be and their destination. Rather, this is just giving some guidance of about how far off the spell is.

Also, I tend to think that the spell would generally "follow" terrain. That is, if I'm teleporting 100 miles East onto a mountaintop, if I'm off-target I wouldn't end up in mid-air over the base of the mountain, I'd end up somewhere on the planet's surface but just not where I wanted.

And, the eight directions you can go are designed to just be "in a random direction". If you try to teleport to the North Pole of a planet, even though every direction you might be off is "South" I would still roll for a random direction to be off in. And you might be on a plane of some sort where the concepts of compass directions make no sense, or in space (does anybody still like the Spelljammer setting?) where you may be off in a random direction, but not really one labelled "North" or "South".

### So the DM just picks somewhere off-target that will make for an interesting story

Much like needing to pick interesting encounters and interesting terrain to make the game fun for all, the DM should pick for a place that makes for an interesting challenge for the players. Since it's a bit fuzzy where the players are landing anyway, the DM might pick a nearby empty space, or on top of whatever structure the wall is in, or another place altogether. Or maybe, especially if it's a part of lore in the world about past Wizards who tried to teleport and were never heard from again, or were found buried at some point, it could make sense for the location to be embedded in some rock or wall or something, although that's probably not something I'd choose in my campaign.

Answer (score 2):

I daresay the Teleport spell would inherently defend against such an event occurring. Given the way the dice rolls are done, "Similar Area" is considered 'worse' than Off Target, and the rules for Similar Area are "You and your group (or the target object) wind up in a different area that's visually or thematically similar to the target area." Inside a wall would not be thematically similar to NOT inside a wall.

The fact that "Mishap" exists suggests to me that this is the likelihood of something going painfully wrong. Your players will be deciding whether to use Teleport on the basis of that chance - raising it by making Off-Target equate to Mishap will make the spell much less appealing. That's fine, if it's a deliberate choice, but as a player if I thought that Off-Target was the same as Mishap I would not use the spell - it happens too often.

We once prevented a TPK with a teleport, that ended up being Off-Target. It would have really violated the rule of fun if we ended up in a wall. Teleport would just not get used, and that limits your ability as a DM to bounce people around the world (Off-Target teleports are an awesome way to get your players somewhere interesting).

Answer (score -4):

If your DM prefers to stick to physics, then you are not just dead, but your remains and items have been destroyed too.  On the plus side, if there were any bad guys nearby, you took them out too.

If your DM sticks more to the rules then you have a pretty good chance of suffering some damage and ending up in a random location.  There is no guarantee you will appear at ground level either.  So.. generally speaking, don't use teleportation unless you have already setup at least one well-known place that you can teleport to reliably.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour] for an intro to how we do things around here.  This answer could be improved by adding sources to back it up - why would "physics" result in destruction?  What rules are you referncing when you say you "have a pretty good chance" of the consequences you mention?  What chance, exactly?  These claims need to be justified by citations or play experience.